# How to create a CloudWatch Alarm using two High Cardinality Dimension Metrics

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I am considering a design which will create the following metrics to AWS CloudWatch:

**transactionWriteCount**: Number of "write" operations in a block

**transactionUpdateCount**: Number of "update" operations performed in a block

Both metrics use `BlockNumber` as a dimension. Blocknumber is increasing on the basis of time which makes it a high cardinality dimension. Expectation is that the write operation and update operation count for a block should be the same for a network. Both these operations are performed by different lambda invocations over a period of time.

I want to create a CloudWatch Alarm that triggers whenever the difference between transactionWriteCount and transactionUpdateCount for any specific block is greater than 0. Since the `BlockNumber` dimension value constantly changes as new blocks are processed. This seems to prevent the direct use of CloudWatch MetricMath. Cloudwatch Metrics `Search()` operation doesn't let you create alarms as well. what is the best solution for this scenario?